# Install virtualbox 4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Нужно установить virtualbox 4 на Ubuntu 16.04 не нашел ответа

Comment: Ответа на какой вопрос?

Answer (score 4):

Действительно, из вашего вопроса не понятно в чем у Вас трудность. Насколько я помню, в стандартном репозитории Ubuntu как раз четвертая версия Virtualbox, можете проверить версию командой:

```
apt search virtualbox
```

Если четвертая, то ставьте командой:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Если не та версия, что Вам нужна, то ставьте, например, из Виртуалбоксовского репозитория:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib" && wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y virtualbox-4.3
```

Ну или скачайте с сайта нужную Вам версию deb пакета и установите через менеджер приложений.